# How to center an HTML element with border that matches width

Tags: html, css, centering

Tricky one, I have an HTML title, with border-top and border-bottom applied on it. 
Can I center it so that the borders are the same width as the element ? 
Now I have to miserably use width, which is not at all a good solution.

See here for a demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KIJAh

**HTML**

```
<div>
<h3 class="removeMe">All your base</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
 padding-top: 30px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;  
 background-color: Moccasin;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.removeMe {
 width:160px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main options I can think of:

1) set h3 to `display: inline` AND set the parent element to have `text-align: center`

Comment: The first one is the answer. Second doesn't center the text

Comment: updated the second one to work - auto margins and position relative with display inline centers the text

Comment: Solution 1 made the trick, however despite update solution 2 doesn't work, can you provide a working example ? Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: Option 2, you'd have to specify a width, I'm realizing, which is something you said you didn't want to have to do... but here's a fiddle anyways http://jsfiddle.net/9kA9G/

Answer (score 2):

You could add `display: inline` to your h3 selector:

```
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline;
}
```

This will of course affect the layout behavior.

**EDIT** OP wants the text centered:

To keep the text centered add `text-align: center` to the parent:

```
div {
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    background-color: Moccasin;
     text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Text is not centered this way.

Comment: That is what I meant with the layout behavior. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline-block; on the h3 instead of display:block;

Comment: How do you center the text then ?

Comment: Put text-align:center on the div.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, display:inline, but if that breaks your layout and you don't want to fix it. You might want to give table a try. Its seems to work the way you want it to in your demo. Not 100% sure its still viable css though.

```
display: table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to get the heading to be aligned to the center ...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoFKH

Highlighted the div background to make it obvious :/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```css
.heading__wrap {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.heading__wrap .heading__title {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7f4cab;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading__wrap">
  <h2 class="heading__title">Music to Our Ears</h2>
</div>
```